# How to enforce multi factor authentication in external azure active directories

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have AAD with custom enteprise sign on page and multi factor authentication enabled. When logging to any of the application registered in this AAD, MFA is enfornced. Now, I want to enforce MFA even when somebody adds accounts from this AAD as guests to some external AAD.

**However, when I create new AAD and add guests user from previous AAD (with MFA enabled), MFA is not enforced.** 
For example, I create VSTS connected to this newly created AAD, log in with my company account (which is guest here), I go to our custom ESO, but I'm logged in without MFA.

Now, where is the problem? In the parent AAD or in the newly created AAD?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to ensure that the guest users require MFA is to create a group policy for conditional access and check the box "Require MFA" for all members of that group.

Please see if [this blog post](https://jankesblog.com/2017/09/secure-guest-access-to-microsoft-teams-with-azure-mfa/) helps. It outlines in detail how to enable/require MFA for external users.

[image]